# How to batch download files from url with two range in linux

Tags: linux, batch-file, download, range

I want to download file from a site that provides download link as

http://abc.com/blahblahblah/XXX/PQR/XXX.jpeg

here XXX change over a range.
i have tried using curl but it wont work it start downloading combinations of both the ranges. 
i want both XXX before and after PQR to change simultaneously (both have to be same all the time)

Comment: You state "*here XXX change over a range*". How do the XXX values change, what kind of range should we think of? Can you give an example that more clearly illustrates the set of download links?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using a [bash for loop](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/)?

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in {001..020}; do
    wget "http://abc.com/blahblahblah/$x/PQR/$x""_jpeg.jpeg"
done
```

If you wanted `XXX` in the path and `YYY` in the file name independent of each other, you could nest two `for` loops thusly:

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in {001..020}; do
    for y in {001..099}; do
        wget "http://abc.com/blahblahblah/$x/PQR/$y""_jpeg.jpeg"
    done
done
```

Comment: i tried it , i think i missed something that i should have written,
its is such that in the end where its written XXX.jpg, it like XXX_jpeg.jpeg
so whenever i run the bash command it interprets XXX_jpeg as on entity ,so what it does is that its changes the first xxx and omits the other

Comment: I modified my examples to illustrate how to keep the underscore from clobbering your variables.